# kendo UI grid angular

Tags: css, angular, kendo-grid

Is it possible to customize themes when using KendoUI GRID. Need features like hovering over rows, default sorting on multiple columns and some other features. Does kendo grid have support for such customization? If yes is there some documentation?

Comment: Which angular are you using. Here you have an example for Angular 1.x https://dojo.telerik.com/@sehaxx/ePeQatOR everything out of the box. And for the Latest angular check this site: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/styling/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add hover and other events to KendoUI GRID via jQuery.
Just select the specific row:

```
$(".k-grid > table > tbody > tr:hover,
.k-grid-content > table > tbody > tr:hover").mouseenter
```

There's default sort for rows. Here's full [documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid) about KendoUI grid and its events. Here's default [sorting](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/sortable)
You can make custom template for the [grid](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/altrowtemplate) width specific classes.
And you can use [column commands](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.command#columns.command.click) to handle click events.

Comment: Thank you! But the documentation you have shared is all related to jquery and I am working with angular. I am new to front end development, could you share some similar examples for angular?

Answer (score 0):

You can either overwrite built-in styling directly in CSS or use any of the other available approaches for customizing the themes, as described in the DOCS:

[Customizing themes](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/styling/#toc-customizing-themes)

If you go for the CSS option, you can target the hovered Grid rows and customize their appearance like this:

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
styles: [`
  .k-grid .k-grid-table tr:hover {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
  }
`]
```

[PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/ThqO95do6elYVqLQxE8s?p=preview)

The default sorting by a single or multiple columns can be defined via providing the respective sorting descriptors to the Grid configuration (via the sort property):

[DOCS](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/sorting/#toc-setting-the-direction)

Comment: That's Perfect !

Comment: That's Perfect !
Also, i need your opinion on kendo UI grid. Can we fully customize it? for example, i need to sort the columns based on multiple columns by default, i need to remove funnel images when filtering with dates, etc. 
Can we achieve all this?